# Как установить язык в headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в "Accept-Language" установить язык через jquery?
Я определяю язык через "Accept-Language". Пытаюсь, чтобы все запросы шли с запросом другого языка, но headers не устанавливается.

```
<script>
var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.set('Accept-Language', 'en-EN,');
    console.log(myHeaders.get('Accept-Language'))
</script>
```

Comment: Вопрос не ясный если честно. листинг кода или хотя бы опишите кейс.

Comment: @Kirill, Я пишу сайт на aspnet мне нужно сделать локализацию для сайта, Вопрос в том как сделать удобно через Headers или через кеш сохранять локализацию, то через Headers не понимаю как сохранять его

Comment: Я не знаю как это в asp.net, но в приложениях, основаных на php, например, обычно локализации строятся по-другому.  Выбор языка сайта определяется наличием в урле кода языка. site.com/en/some-ulr или site.com/ru/some-ulr. На основании этого происходит роутинг и подстановка локализаций. Может вам стоит копать в этом направлении?

Comment: @Kirill, Как это называется когда в url стоит язык? То я могу лишь найти где стоит язык в гет параметре

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь про ajax запросы в jquery, то все есть документации. В частности сигнатуры вызова

```
jQuery.get( [settings ] )
jQuery.ajax( [settings ] )
```

[объект settings описан в документации](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) имеет свойство `headers`, которое вам и нужно

> An object of additional header key/value pairs to send along with requests using the XMLHttpRequest transport. The header X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest is always added, but its default XMLHttpRequest value can be changed here. Values in the headers setting can also be overwritten from within the beforeSend function.

как видно есть несколько путей изменения заголовков. Первый очевидно указать в данном поле (объект ключ-значение заголовков) (`headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-EN`).
Второе, указано, что можно перекрыть в `beforeSend`.

Третье, и для вас, вероятно, наиболее интересное - глобальные настройки [`$.ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), опции те же самые и будут применяться для всех вызовов.

Comment: @teram, но ведь при переходе на другую страницу, он не будет передаваться. А можно, чтобы сохранялся хеадер или лучше сделать локализацию через cash?

Comment: @chilo5432 дак речь не про аякс?